# How do I configure OpenSplice DDS for 100,000 nodes?

Tags: scale, distributed-computing, data-distribution-service, opensplice

What is the right approach to use to configure OpenSplice DDS to support 100,000 or more nodes?

Can I use a hierarchical naming scheme for partition names, so "headquarters.city.location_guid_xxx" would prevent packets from leaving a location, and "company.city*" would allow samples to align across a city, and so on? Or would all the nodes know about all these partitions just in case they wanted to publish to them?

The durability services will choose a master when it comes up. If one durability service is running on a Raspberry Pi in a remote location running over a 3G link what is to prevent it from trying becoming the master for "headquarters" and crashing?

I am experimenting with durability settings in a remote node such that I use location_guid_xxx but for the "headquarters" cloud server I use  a Headquarters

On the remote client I might to do this:

```
<Merge scope="Headquarters" type="Ignore"/>
<Merge scope="location_guid_xxx" type="Merge"/>
```

so a location won't be master for the universe, but can a durability service within a location still be master for that location?

If I have 100,000 locations does this mean I have to have all of them listed in the "Merge scope" in the ospl.xml file located at headquarters? I would think this alone might limit the size of the network I can handle.

I am assuming that this product will handle this sort of Internet of Things scenario. Has anyone else tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the scale of your system I think you should seriously consider the use of Vortex-Cloud (see these slides http://slidesha.re/1qMVPrq). Vortex Cloud will allow you to better scale your system as well as deal with NAT/Firewall. Beside that, you'll be able to use TCP/IP to communicate from your Raspberry Pi to the cloud instance thus avoiding any problem related to NATs/Firewalls.

Before getting to your durability question, there is something else I'd like to point out. If you try to build a flat system with 100K nodes you'll generate quite a bit of discovery information. Beside generating some traffic, this will be taking memory on your end applications. If you use Vortex-Cloud, instead, we play tricks to limit the discovery information. To give you an example, if you have a data-write matching 100K data reader, when using Vortex-Cloud the data-writer would only match on end-point and thus reducing the discovery information by 100K times!!!

Finally, concerning your durability question, you could configure some durability service as alignee only. In that case they will never become master.

HTH.

A+